# "Big" and "Diminutive" are what kind of words...?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What do you call a word that look different than it means? For example, the words "big" and "diminutive"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, there is a word for this: *heterological*.

It doesn't get used much, because it was invented primarily to express a form of [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).